# sql descending alphabetical inside order by case example (firebird)

Tags: sql, case, firebird, alphabetical

This needs to be done in Firebird with FlameRobin

my problem is very simple but I stil need help with it

```
Select * from Clients

order by Case town

when 'amsterdam' Then 1
when 'rotterdam' Then 2
when 'maastricht' Then 3
else 4 end,
Case Gender 
when null then 1
when 'Male' then 2
when 'Female' then 3
else 4 end,
```

---From Here it goes wrong what I want--

```
Case name
when null then 1
when asc then 2    ( and here I want the names alphabetical descending )
else 3 end
```

because sql is so limited I need to some help here

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html the last paragraph outlines this situation.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with you name ordering.  If there a name value called `asc` that you are wanting to somehow trigger descending ordering?

Comment: I am using Firebird (my bad), my value is not called as (but they are just names) I was under the impression that asc was used to alphabetical order things ... Guess I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off building those calculated fields in your select and then working with them for ordering like this:

```
SELECT *,
    (CASE town
        WHEN 'amsterdam' THEN 1
        WHEN 'rotterdam' THEN 2
        WHEN 'maastricht' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END CASE) as town_order,
    CASE gender
        WHEN ...
        ...
        ELSE 4
    END CASE) as gender_order,
    CASE gender
        WHEN ...
        ...
        ELSE 3
    END CASE) as name_order
ORDER BY town_order ASC, gender_order ASC, name_order ASC, name DESC
```

Of course this would be a VERY non-optimal query, not able to use any sort of indexes for sorting.  If you really want to query efficiently, you should add specific `town_order`, `gender_order`, etc. fields to your table and place indexes on them.